# I need to make the ASPSession cookies created by IIS HttpOnly

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I dont have access to IIS server, but I need to make the ASPSession cookies created by IIS HttpOnly. So my question is that how can I make the cookies HttpOnly by coding and not by any setting on IIS ? Please help its urgent and I have been looking for the solution but didn't get anything that related to my problem. I know the server version is IIS 6. On my testing server I have used ISAPI filter and it solved my problem but for that I needed to access the IIS and add ASAPI filter there which I cant do on the live server.

Comment: Do you mean in classic asp, asp.net, or both?  There's some useful information here - http://forums.iis.net/t/1168473.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET 2.0 or greater, you can turn it on in the Web.config file. In the `<system.web>` section, add the following line:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

You can edit this programmatically : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=102